# Calling a Main Activity Shows Activity Not Found Exception in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

this is my main activity. i want to call main activity again if action done. but it say activity not found

### LayoutActivity

```
<activity
            android:name="com.layout.LayoutActivity"
            android:label="V-Alert Registration" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Calling the `LayoutActivity` that is the Main Activity this is the code i used to call the layout activity(Main activity) it shows Activity Not Found

```
if(i>=1)
  {
   Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"You Registerd already with one mail\n Delete the                   mail and Register with new mail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         try{
                       Intent obj=new Intent("com.layout.LayoutActivity");
                       startActivity(obj);}

                catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                            }
           }
```

Comment: from which class you starting the LayoutActivity?

Comment: it starts from FiveActivity

Comment: Then the **FiveActivity** should be the LAUNCHER.  is **FiveActivity** start automatically when start your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent obj=new Intent(FiveActivity.this,LayoutActivity.class);
startActivity(obj);
finish();
```

Comment: This let you open the LayoutActivity but created a new one instead of going back to the old one @user2838776. Careful

Comment: if its helpful upvote the answer.You can also finish current activity.please check for updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In Your program use:

```
Intent obj = new Intent(); 
obj.setClassName("com.layout.LayoutActivity"); // Are you sure?? this is your class package name 
startActivity(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 if(i>=1)
      {
       Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"You Registerd already with one mail\n Delete the                   mail and Register with new mail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             try{
                         Intent obj=new Intent(FiveActivity.this,LayoutActivity.class);
               startActivity(obj);}

                    catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                                }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call like this way : This will call your particular activity again.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest by this...

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.layout.LayoutActivity"
        android:label="V-Alert Registration" >
    </activity>
```

And start your LayoutActivity by this...

```
if(i>=1){

    Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"You Registerd already with one mail\n Delete the mail 
                       and Register with new mail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        Intent obj=new Intent(FiveActivity.this, LayoutActivity.class);
        startActivity(obj);

    }catch(Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                            }
    }
}
```